# Chrome (58v) webdriverio is not running, firefox is running

Tags: javascript, selenium, google-chrome, webdriver-io, wdio-v4

I was able to run Firefox and Chrome (automation tests locally), yet it worked some time ago. I am getting some error during trying run them on Chrome.

**My versions:**

- Windows 10 64 bit
- Chrome version 58
- Node 6.10.3

I am getting the following **error** in the console (when I am trying to run Chrome): `ERROR: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. (UnknownError:13) Chrome`.

In the console were **selenium-server** was run I got: `os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_121' Driver info: driver.version: unknown`

And also:

> Executing: [new session: Capabilities [{rotatable=true, seleniumProtocol=WebDriver, locationContextEnabled=true, loggingPrefs=org.openqa.selenium.logging.LoggingPreferences@8ac8f23, browserName=chrome, javascriptEnabled=true, chromeOptions={args=[--start-maximized, --start-fullscreen]}, handlesAlerts=true, maxInstances=1, requestOrigins={name**=webdriverio, version=4.6.2**, url=http://webdriver.io}}]])
>   INFO - Creating a new session for Capabilities [{rotatable=true, seleniumProtocol=WebDriver, locationContextEnabled=true, loggingPrefs=org.openqa.selenium.logging.LoggingPreferences@, browserName=chrome, javascriptEnabled=true, chromeOptions={args=[--start-maximized, --start-fullscreen]}, handlesAlerts=true, maxInstances=1, requestOrigins={name=webdriverio, version=4.6.2, url=http://webdriver.io}}]
>   ERROR - org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: -1073741819 (Exit value: -1073741819)
>   WARN - Exception thrown

I am using **WebdriverIO** and the tests are written in JavaScript.

**package.json** content:

```
dependencies": {
    "chai": "3.5.0",
    "chai-as-promised": "6.0.0",
    "chai-string": "1.3.0",
    "chai-subset": "1.5.0",
    "chai-things": "0.2.0",
    "jsonfile": "3.0.0",
    "moment": "2.18.1",
    "node-gyp": "3.6.1",
    "node-ninja": "1.0.2",
    "node-uuid": "1.4.8",
    "webdriverio": "4.8.0"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "mocha": "^3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "6.24.1",
    "babel-core": "6.24.1",

    "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "6.23.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "6.23.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "6.24.1",
    "babel-register": "6.24.1",
    "chromedriver": "2.29.0",
    "cross-env": "4.0.0",
    "eslint": "^3.19.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "15.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^5.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "7.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-webdriverio": "1.0.1",
    "express": "4.15.2",
    "geckodriver": "1.6.1",
    "marked": "0.3.6",
    "marked-terminal": "2.0.0",
    "mocha": "3.3.0",
    "mocha-babel": "3.0.3",
    "mocha-junit-reporter": "1.13.0",
    "mocha-parallel-tests": "1.2.9",
    "mocha-prepare": "0.0.1",
    "mocha-traceur": "2.1.0",
    "progress": "2.0.0",
    "request": "2.81.0",
    "selenium-standalone": "6.4.1",
    "supertest": "3.0.0",
    "tedious": "2.0.0",
    "tedious-connection-pool": "1.0.5",
    "uuid": "3.0.1",
    "wdio-allure-reporter": "0.1.2",
    "wdio-browserstack-service": "0.1.4",
    "wdio-concise-reporter": "0.1.2",
    "wdio-dot-reporter": "0.0.8",
    "wdio-firefox-profile-service": "0.0.3",
    "wdio-jasmine-framework": "0.3.1",
    "wdio-json-reporter": "0.2.1",
    "wdio-junit-reporter": "0.3.0",
    "wdio-mocha-framework": "0.5.10",
    "wdio-phantomjs-service": "0.2.2",
    "wdio-sauce-service": "0.4.0",
    "wdio-selenium-standalone-service": "0.0.8",
    "wdio-spec-reporter": "0.1.0"
```

I removed **node_modules** folder, then installed again via **npm** (locally), but it did not help.

Firefox is run when I switch in **wdio.config.js** from Chrome to Firefox. One of my friend is using the same version of Chrome and it works.

In the console is written **`webdriverio, version=4.6.2`**, so different version than in **package.json**, but should I install another version (not the newest), or how can I do this?

Thanks and regards.

**UPDATE:
wdio config file**

pastebin com/Jd9WrH7B

Comment: Check with your friend, the chromedriver version he is using with chrome and also Selenium version. Try to run your scrips with the same version.

Comment: run with the same version it did not help:( node js also the same npm also the same,..all was uninstalled and installed again (python npm node..etc) there was some problem with IP 192...aftter goin did not work now it works..but stil the same error:(

Answer (score 1):

You have the following alternatives:

**1.)** If you want to continue running your test cases via `npm run <testName>` with the latest version (`"webdriverio": "4.8.0"`) then:

**a.** Either update your global WebdriverIO instance: `npm install -g webdriverio@latest`, or `npm install -g webdriverio@4.8.0` (this will update your global WebdriverIO version to `4.8.0`);

**b.** Or, run your test case with your current version of WebdriverIO via: `./node_modules/.bin/wdio <wdioConfigFile>`(in your case `wdio.config.js`). This should be ran from your project root;

**c.** Try to force updates on your dependencies via `npm update` in your project root; (this is more of a **Hail Marry!**).

**Note:** These will only work if you already have **selenium-standalone**
 as a service in your `wdio.config.js` file (`services: ['selenium-standalone']`).

**2.)** If you still have issues, comment the **selenium-standalone** service line from your `wdio.config.js` file and start your own `chromedriver` selenium-standalone instance:

From your console of choice (, or `cmd`) use this: `java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=C:\selenium\chromedriver.exe -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.0.1.jar -port 4444`.

**Note:** You need to have the latest **[chromedriver.exe](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads)** binary in the folder where you're launching the server from, as well as the [**selenium-standalone**](http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/) `.jar`. I have them in `C:\selenium\`.

Let me know if any of these help you! Like I said, it could be anything judging by that error. At least you're narrowing it down.

Comment: @pav OK, so I've installed all your `package.json` dependencies (project got to `177 MB`, lol) and ran a few tests and everything worked fine, both with `selenium-standalone` server, or `wdio-selenium-standalone-service`. Only thing I can think of right now, is your `wdio.config.js` file. Can you add the contents of your config file in the original question in an **Update:**  section at the end?

Comment: Thanks... i put on pastebin com